# Firebase Storage iOS put file completion handler called before upload finishes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was trying to upload videos to Firebase Storage, and when the upload finishes, I store the location of this video file to an object in the database, my code is as below:

```
Storage.storage().reference(withPath: mediaURL!).putFile(from: localCacheURL, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("❗️failed to upload video")
    } else {
        print("a video is uploaded")
        json = ["text": "", "image": "", "video": mediaURL!, "connections": []]
        upload()
    }
})
```

But I found the completion handler called before the upload actually finishes, I went to Firebase console and downloaded the uploaded file, it was unfinished.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

One for your reason for your problem may be that your cache file is somehow broken. To figure it out what's happening you need more information.

You can do that by observing the `FIRFileStorageUploadTask`which is returned by `putFile`.

```
let uploadTask = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: mediaURL!).putFile(from: localCacheURL, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("❗️failed to upload video")
    } else {
        print("a video is uploaded")
        json = ["text": "", "image": "", "video": mediaURL!, "connections": []]
        // unclear what this does 
        // looks strange if it's just a notification rename it into something like videoUploadCompleted 
        // if it needs the json stuff pass it as parameter to make it thread safe
        upload() 
    }
})

uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
   print("\(snapshot.progress)") 
}
```

It will give you something like:

```
<NSProgress: 0x604000123020> :
Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0062 / Completed: 1867836 of
301329576
```

You can also get more information about failures by using

```
 uploadTask.observe(.failure) { snapshot in
    if let error = snapshot.error as? NSError {
      print ("Error : \(error)")
    }
}
```

For more details about monitoring and error handling see also [Upload Files on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) Firebase Documentation